# Why isn't my swift async function "awating"?

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a hard time learning the new Swift async functions and getting them to perform in the correct order.

I want to make my loadData() function "await" or WAIT when calling it but when printing the order that should be 1,2,3 it prints out as 1,3,2 which means after calling the function it goes to the next line of code instead of waiting for the results of vm.loadData()

I am getting the warning "No 'async' operations occur within 'await' expression" where I try to make the call but I thought by putting the call in a task would make it work?

Below is my code, what am I doing wrong?

**VIEW**

```
struct Button: View {
   let vm = ViewModel()
   
   var body: some View {
      Circle().onTapGesture { doSomething }
   }

   func doSomething() {
       print("1")
       Task {
            // WARNING: No 'async' operations occur within 'await' expression
            await vm.loadData()
       }
       print("3")

   }
}
```

**VIEW MODEL**

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

     @Published var data: [String] = []
    
     func loadData() {
        Task {
            do {
                let dataArray = try await DataApi.loadData()
                if !dataArray.isEmpty {
                    self.data = dataArraay
                }
                print("2")
            } catch {
                <HANDLE ERRORS>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**API CALL**

```
class DataApi {
    static func loadData() async throws -> [String] {
         // MAKE API CALL
         do {
             // decode data
             return data
         } catch {
             throw ResponseError.decodingError("\(error)")
         }
        return []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`vm.loadData()` is not an async method, so the compiler is complaining that you call it with `await` in your SwiftUI view.

At its most basic, Swift's async rule is: any time you use the `await` keyword, you **must** be calling a method that's declared with `async`, and if you declare a method with `async`, you **must** use `await` when you call it.

In `ViewModel`, you're using `Task` correctly as a "bridge" between synchronous mode and asynchronous mode. You call `vm.loadData()` synchronously, and an async task calls the async API; when the data comes back, it stores the returned value in a property.

Creating that Task returns immediately, so `vm.loadData()` finishes executing while the task is still running.

That means that your call to `vm.loadData()` doesn't need to be wrapped in another task. You can call it directly, and it'll create the background async work for you. That simplifies your calling code:

```
Circle().onTapGesture { vm.loadData() }
```

Answer (score 4):

`await` means only that you can proceed with the result of the line within the task. It does not mean that the enclosing task is *synchronous*.

The warning is displayed because `loadData` in `ViewModel` is not `async`.

This is a complete asynchronous version

```
func doSomething() {
   print("1")
   Task {
       await vm.loadData()
       print("3")
   }
}
```

ViewModel

```
@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

     @Published var data: [String] = []
    
     func loadData() async {
         do {
             self.data = try await DataApi.loadData()
         } catch {
             self.data = []
             print(error)   
         }
         print("2")
     }
}
```

API call

```
class DataApi {
    static func loadData() async throws -> [String] {
         // try await MAKE API CALL
         // try decode data
         return data
    }
}
```

It's recommended to hand over errors to the caller when marked with `throws`. The API call is supposed to throw the `ResponseError`